# Stack Docs: How to delete my (very bad) contribution?

Tags: discussion, documentation

I made a [very bad contribution](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2B%2B/1810/the-virtual-keyword#t=20160725175347156649) which I immediately regret. I'd prefer to just kill it and forget about it, but it seems impossible to delete. How do I delete it?

The screen after trying to delete is this: 
[image]

Comment: Please go submit your edit again, but just click delete on the topic without editing prior. [This is a bug](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329538/1896169); it made your reviewers confused

Answer (score 6):

Click the edit button at the top of the topic:

[image: screenshot of the edit button]

Then, a trash button will appear just next to the edit one:

[image: screenshot of the delete button]

Click it to delete the topic.

Comment: Thanks - I did that, but it is considered an 'edit' and needs community approval to delete.

Comment: Deleting a topic == deleting all examples, and deleting one or more examples is considered an edit to a topic.

Comment: Ah yes... I've followed your instructions. It's considered an edit though, and needs reviewed and approved apparently. So I'm still awaiting approval for the edit to delete the topic.

Comment: @NonCreature0714 it might also help with review if you give a clear and convincing edit summary.