# Deleting a topic after some edits makes it hard to tell that the topic has been deleted

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, documentation-topics

NonCreature0714 [decided to delete the entire topic created by her/him-self.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329493/1896169) Unfortunately, the edit got rejected, because [it doesn't appear that the entire topic was being deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/25032):

[image]

This happens when edits were made to the draft, *then* delete is clicked to delete the topic, as [confirmed by Shog9](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/31918503#31918503).

Answer (score 3):

The deletion is a *tiny* bit easier to read now that we shade the box red:

[image: Deleted example]

But we still show useless diffs:

[image: These changes are not going to be reflected in a deleted example.]

I think the right thing to do on a deleted topic or section is to ignore any changes made within the body of the affected text. These changes should be discarded the same way any unsaved changes are discarded after you delete a file and discard the edit buffer.

Answer (score 2):

We're making a couple of changes to address this:

1. What Jon mentioned, with the new Review Queue deletions get an all red background.
2. Going forward proposing a deletion will remove other changes from that draft. It doesn't really make to edit and delete at the same time, and introduces weird versions of a topic into it's timeline. This means anything that ends up with a red background in review shouldn't have any diffs in it.
3. When looking at old changes that deleted a topic we're now suppressing diffs. Technically we still have the data, and those edits still "happened" (at the same time as the delete, so they're not easily reachable) but consistency with #2 is maintained, at least in presentation.

These changes are all live as of the last deploy.